# Metatrader 5: How to get take profit level of closed position?

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

In the MQL5 language, to get the current TP of an open position (hedging mode), I use

```cpp
if (PositionSelectByTicket(positionId)) {
   return PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP);
}
```

Once the position is closed, I search for the corresponding ENTRY_IN deal, and query the corresponding order for the TP:

```cpp
if (HistorySelectByPosition(positionId)) {
   for (int i = HistoryDealsTotal()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      ulong dealId = HistoryDealGetTicket(i);
      if (HistoryDealGetInteger(dealId, DEAL_POSITION_ID) != positionId) continue;
      if ((ENUM_DEAL_ENTRY)HistoryDealGetInteger(dealId, DEAL_ENTRY) != DEAL_ENTRY_IN) continue;
      ulong orderId = HistoryDealGetInteger(dealId, DEAL_ORDER);
      if (HistoryOrderSelect(orderId)) {
         return HistoryOrderGetDouble(orderId, ORDER_TP);
      }
   }
}
```

However, this only works if the TP was set directly while opening the position. If the TP was set later, this does not work. I examined all deals and orders corresponding to the `positionId`, but was not able to find the TP anywhere.

What is a robust method to obtain the TP of a closed position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the MQL5 forum I got the following suggestion from @fxsaber: the DEAL_TP property of the DEAL_ENTRY_OUT deal contains the last TP set. That indeed works!

```cpp
if (HistorySelectByPosition(positionId)) {
   for (int i = HistoryDealsTotal()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      ulong dealId = HistoryDealGetTicket(i);
      if (HistoryDealGetInteger(dealId, DEAL_POSITION_ID) != positionId) continue;
      if ((ENUM_DEAL_ENTRY)HistoryDealGetInteger(dealId, DEAL_ENTRY) != DEAL_ENTRY_OUT) continue;
      return HistoryDealGetDouble(dealId, DEAL_TP);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mt5.history_deals_get(position=result.order)[1].profit
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however this doesn't look like MQL5 code to me. Is it perhaps Python? I guess this returns the profit of a deal, not the take profit that was set prior.